# How to check if a random button is pressed?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Short question I am programming an application in visual studio and would like to detect if a random button is pressed (maybe short code and not programming all the possible buttons)... Is there a short way to do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Post some code that what you have tried

Comment: Loop through controls that are buttons and addhandler to them for your procedure/method...

Comment: Do you mean you want to detect if someone is randomly clicking on button or do you want to know which button was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

A button click handler can handle more than one button click.

```
Private Sub Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, Which button is pressed does not matter. Shortly said from the moment any button is pressed on the keyboard I would like to register it. I forgot to mention it had to be a keyboard button...

Comment: @dbasnett's answer does the trick IMO - the sender can be used to determine the button that was pressed using .Name, .Text, or other property e.g. .Tag. You can quickly build this in the IDE - select all the buttons that you what to track and add a Click event.

Comment: Take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1